# Sharepoint Online, Classic mode - Email fields do not reflect those in the Forms

Tags: email

I have form fields set as desired but my email (default notification using the Assigned To field) does not include the same fields in the same order. Any suggestions?

[image: Content Order Settings]

[image: Email Resulting]

Comment: a screen shot would be useful to explain the result you are looking to achieve

Comment: Screen shots added. Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: You could try using Sharepoint Designer, since it can be used to customise the fields embedded in the 'assigned to' email.  The order the fields appear can be modified using Designer.  It is free to download from Microsoft.

Comment: The "Assigned to" is a system workflow which I cannot edit. The columns update as I change them in the in the Task - there is just not a pattern to how it updates. It even includes items that I have hidden. I could start a custom workflow I suppose, using a new custom people picker but have experienced issues in the past doing that on our Sharepoint.

Comment: I am using SP 2013, so it sounds like you are using a newer version than me.

Comment: I think we are using SP 2013 or Enterprise or Online in Classic view. Perhaps I just don't know how to find the email template in Designer.

Comment: hmm, perhaps you are using a Task List - I believe this type of list has a built-in 'Assigned To' email.  You should be able to use Sharepoint Designer to edit it, assuming you are using SP 2013.  I don't know about Enterprise or Online.

Comment: Yes. I am using a Task list - I apologize for not mentioning that. I have been unsuccessful at locating even the workflow that is used with the Assigned To field. If I could locate that, then I could edit the email template. I thought it was probably because this is a "system" template?